# How to detect non-ASCII character in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, ascii

I'm parsing multiple XML files with Python 2.7, there are some strings like: `string ="[2,3,13,37–41,43,44,46]"`. I split them to get a list of all elements, and then I have to detect elements with "–" like "37–41", but it turns out this is not a regular dash, it's a non-ASCII character:

```
elements = [u'2', u'3', u'13', u'37\u201341', u'43', u'44', u'46']
```

So I need something like

```
for e in elements:
  if "–" in e:
      # do something about it
```

If use that non-ASCII char in this if expression, then I get an error: `"SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file..."`.

I tried to replace the `if` expression with this re method:

```
re.search('\xe2', e)
```

but it's not the case again. So I'm looking for a way to either convert that non-ASCII char to a regular ASCII "-" or use the ASCII number directly in the search expression.

Comment: The elements containing only non-ascii dash and numbers?

Comment: @EbraHim yes. I want to detect elements like 37-41 , so I can expand them to be like 37 38 39 40 41. I can do the second part easily but I have problem with the non-ascii character.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?  ASCII characters (0-127) only, or do you include ISO Latin 1 (0-255)?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 with 128 ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

elements = [u'2', u'3', u'13', u'37\u201341', u'43', u'44', u'46']

for e in elements:
    if (re.sub('[ -~]', '', e)) != "":
        #do something here
        print "-"
```

`re.sub('[ -~]', '', e)` will strip out any valid ASCII characters in `e` (Specifically, replace any valid ASCII characters with ""), only non-ASCII characters of e are remained.

Hope this help

Comment: it worked pretty fine. just needed to change last print to to `print  e` and it printed out exactly the element I was looking for. I would appreciated if you can give me a link to the documentation because the syntax is little bit strange.

Comment: I think this code is actually fairly obscure - is there really anyone who sees what `if (re.sub('[ -~]', '', e)) != ""` does right away?

Answer (score 16):

You can check the if the character value is between 0 - 127.

```
for c in someString:
    if 0 <= ord(c) <= 127:
        # this is a ascii character.
    else:
        # this is a non-ascii character. Do something.
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
>>> import re
>>> non_decimal = re.compile(r'[^\d.]+')
>>>
>>> string ="[2,3,13,37–41,43,44,46]"
>>> new_str = string.replace("[","")
>>> new_str = new_str.replace("]","")
>>> lst = new_str.split(",")
>>> for element in lst:
    if element.isdigit():
        print element
    else:
        toexpand = non_decimal.sub('f', str(element))
        toexpand = toexpand.split("f")
        for i in range(int(toexpand[0]),int(toexpand[1])+1,1):
            print i


2
3
13
37
38
39
40
41
43
44
46
>>>
```

Comment: I want to detect the element containing the non-ascii dash, like 37-41. not ignore it.

Comment: I still get UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) . I'm using PyCharm IDE, may that caused the problem?

Comment: Oops! Updated, but late :)

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your whole question. Way too simple and not flexible. I do this whenever I have this error.

I usually open up an **interactive python shell** and I type in:

`print [ln for ln in open("filename.py", "rb").readlines() if "\xe2" in ln]`

That gives you lines with \ex2. Then try finding it in your editor.and try removing the character.

Answer (score 1):

For a more generalized approach you can use libraries such as [`chardet`](https://github.com/chardet/chardet) (pure python) or [`cchardet`](https://github.com/PyYoshi/cChardet) (a faster C alternative). Install the module with e.g. with `pip3 install chardet` or `pip3 install cchardet`.

They both have the same API:

```py
import chardet

with open("/etc/hosts", "rb") as fi:
    print(chardet.detect(fi.read()))

# OUTPUT: 
# {'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
```

If the `encoding` key in the dict is not `ascii` then you have non-ascii characters in the file.

Both modules expose command line tools that you can use to detect which of your XML files are non-ASCII:

```bash
find . -iname "*.xml" -exec cchardetect {} +
```

Normally, you would only need to do the detection when working with mysterious legacy data of unknown origin that is not utf-8/unicode.

If you have a hard requirement to convert everything to ASCII then you can do something like:

```py
import unicodedata

unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', 'Verhältnismäßigkeit — 1').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
# OUTPUT
# b'Verhaltnismaigkeit  1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your encoding in your Python program, for example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Usually Python tells you about this issue:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file ./fail.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

After adding the encoying, your code should work just fine.

Comment: it didn't work for me, I'm using PyCharm IDE and I still get UnicodeDecodeError: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: This made sense for Python 2, but doesn't directly solve the problem in the question even then. In Python 3, the default encoding is UTF-8 anyway; you only have to use an encoding comment if you want to use something else than UTF-8 (which you really don't want to, unless you know _exactly_ what you are doing, in which case you would probably not be reading this).